# QGIS more than 3000 raster works slowly

Tags: qgis, raster, performance, mosaic

I need to add to QGIS more than 3000 rasters tif (with pyramids). It works very hard and slowly. So I ask: There's a solution that give's them quickly?.

Comment: This sounds like a lot of data for QGIS to manage. What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps you could do this outside of QGIS and then just load the product in

Comment: I'm surprised you could even load that many into a *graphical map* without crashing the thing. Kudos to QGIS for some good implementation there.

Comment: Hello Nathan. Thanks for answer!... I have a lot of raster with high resolution to enter into a library. I found solution to build by grouping the rastres in many vrt files. I think there's another better solution. what do you mean about: "do this outside of QGIS and then just load the product in"... I tryed to create a qlr file with all the rasters(almost  3000) but it crashed.

Comment: Im curious as to what you want to do with the data once its in QGIS. For example, if you wanted to load them in so you could mosaic them, I would recommend doing this outside of QGIS first

Answer (score 7):

You may see considerable benefit if you load them into a single virtual raster (vrt). You can do that through the processing toolbox, by searching for "build vrt"

Comment: Hello ndawson thank for answer!: I tried to build vrt for all raster (a lot of) files but it crashed.

Comment: Perhaps is goes better with gdalbuildvrt http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html.

Comment: If you're loading all of the rasters into QGIS first, try building the vrt without loading the rasters into QGIS.

Comment: Thanks csk!: RE: Is there a way to doing it by python code?

Comment: Older version of gdalbuildvrt was a Python script and it is still in https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/swig/python/samples/gdal_vrtmerge.py.